# Android C2DM Application

Tags: android

I am developing an application using C2DM. I have received registration id. How can I send it to a Server. Can anyone explain me with code.?

Comment: Hi Vishwa I am also doing a work over C2DM in android for sending notification but now i am not able to get registrationnid form c2dm server you have mention in your question you have got a registration id Please provide code for getting registration id . Thanks in advance .. please please help me ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924589/android-c2dm-programming-example/5219182#5219182

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PHP function to send C2DM messages to a phone, with registration id.

/**
 * Sends a message to the phone.

- @static
- @access public
- @param string $authCode Google authorization code of this server obtained through googleAuthenticate()
- @param string $deviceRegistrationId The device registration id obtained from Google during device registration. Identifies the device.
- @param string $msgType The type of this message (an Application thing). This will also serve as the collapse_key.
- @param string $messageText the message to send to the phone.
- @return boolean True on success or false on failure
  */

> function sendMessageToPhone($authCode,
>   $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType,
>   $messageText) {
>
> ```
> $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
> $data = array(
>     'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
>     'collapse_key' => $msgType,
>     'data.message' => $messageText         
> );
>
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
> if ($headers)
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
>
> // for debugging the request
> //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // for debugging the request
>
> $response = curl_exec($ch);
>
> // for debugging the request
> //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); 
> //   var_dump($response);
>
> curl_close($ch);
>
> return $response; }
> ```